# Which is longer cached by SE robots or browsers, redirect 301 or 302

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, http, 302-redirect

I have looked on Stack Exchange but didn't find the solution for my problem.

The problem: I have a website and want to become an SEO hero. So, I also need to choose status codes...

I know that there are approximately 2 status codes to trigger a redirect.

- 301 - Moved Permanently
- 302 - Moved Temporarily

The question: Which status code stays longer in the cache and how long would that be approximately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there are approximately 2 status codes to trigger a redirect

More like 5 ... 301, 302, 303, 307 and 308.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

> 302 - Moved Temporarily

A 302 should never be cached. Browsers do not ordinarily cache a 302. It is after all "temporary".

> 301 - Moved Permanently

301s are cached by default. Since this is considered a "permanent" redirect, browsers (and possibly intermediary caches) will cache a 301 "aggressively". Without additional cache control headers there is no clear rule for how long the redirect should be cached - it's browser/cache dependent. But suffice to say, it can be a "long time".

However, you should be able to send the appropriate cache control headers (ie. `Cache-Control`/`max-age` and `Expires` HTTP response headers) with the redirect in order to control the caching behaviour.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s